# I heard "ideally every view should be defined in activity", is it true?

Tags: android

I heard **"ideally every view should be defined in activity"**

In other word, I should not create an element out side of the activity
(with the Application Context which is sent from the activity to the class which responsible to create the element)

Example1:

```
Button mButton1 = new Button(this);
```

Example2:

```
Button mButton2 = new Button(mContext);
// The activity sends mContext (GetApplicationContext() in the activity) as an argument
```

In the above **example 1** the element is created in the activity
In the above **example 2** the element is created in the class invoked from the activity and the activity sends the application context to the class

Is the second example a bad practice?
If I dynamically create 500 elements with the second approach, does it create a memory leakage
(Since the application context will live till the app is live and the activity will be garbage collected till the activity dies)

Answer (score 0):

If none of the objects that are created from the activity keep dangling after activity is destroyed, you should be fine with second example as well. This way when activity is destroyed all the objects hosted by it, should be eligible for garbage collection.